# SAS: How to create dates out of month field, day field, and year field

Tags: date, sas

I have the following script for inputting my data and creating a dataset.

```
data HotelRooms;
INFILE '/folders/myfolders/Hotel.dat'  missover;
input RoomNo 1-4 NumbeGuests 7-8InMonth $ Inday $ InYear $ OutMonth $   

OutDay $ OutYear $ UseWireless :$3. DaysUsed RoomType$53-68 RoomRate 69-71;

checkindate=CAT(InMonth,InDay,InYear);
checkoutdate=CAT(OutMonth, OutDay, OutYear);
If UseWireless='YES' then fee=9.95;
run; 
proc print data=HotelRooms noobs;
format checkindate MMDDYY10.;
format checkoutdate MM/DD/YY/10.;
Run;
```

The data loads into the dataset just fine, but when I create a checkin date and a checkout date I run into issues.  When I use CAT I cannot add a date format.  The print does not print any / or - in the date, only mm dd yyyy.  I will need to be able to use the dates for calculations also.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `MISSOVER` could cause mistakes with that INPUT statement.  If the input line is only 70 characters long then RoomRate will be missing, even if there is a number in columns 69 and 70.  In general you should use `TRUNCOVER` instead of `MISSOVER` to fix just that issue.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reading your M/D/Y values as characters, read them as numbers and use the `mdy()` function to create a SAS date from the constituent parts :

```
data HotelRooms;
  INFILE '/folders/myfolders/Hotel.dat'  missover;
  input RoomNo 1-4 NumbeGuests 7-8 
        InMonth Inday InYear
        OutMonth OutDay OutYear 
        UseWireless :$3. DaysUsed RoomType $53-68 RoomRate 69-71;

  checkindate  = mdy(InMonth,InDay,InYear);
  checkoutdate = mdy(OutMonth, OutDay, OutYear);
  if UseWireless = 'YES' then fee = 9.95;
  format checkindate checkoutdate mmddyy10. ;
run; 

proc print data=HotelRooms noobs;
run;
```

Comment: That worked Chris.  Thank you.  Looks like I was trying to make it harder than what it had to be.